# How to use Castle IWcfClientFactory

Tags: castle

how to use IWcfClientFactory from castle wcf facility can any please post an example

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/castle-project-users/SCduXbJapfY/discussion